# hide only some categories from layered navigation in magento

Tags: layered-navigation, category-tree

we are using custom theme and 1.9 version

we have lot of categories in magento site. we have to hide some categories from "layererd navigation".

for some categories we put "NO" for "Include in Navigation Menu " in admin panel.

but still those categories are displaying under "shop by" in layered navigation.

how to hide only some categories from layered navigation.

please help me to find solution....

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Include in navigation menu flag does not apply by default to layered nav.
If you want to do so, you need to rewrite the method `Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Category::_getItemsData`.

You need to replace this

```
$categories = $categoty->getChildrenCategories();
```

With something like this (untested code)

```
    $categories = $categoty->getCollection(); //Yes..$categoty is misspelled on purpose
    $categories->addAttributeToSelect('url_key')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('all_children')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('is_anchor')
        ->setOrder('position', Varien_Db_Select::SQL_ASC)
        ->joinUrlRewrite()
        ->addIdFilter($category->getChildren())
        ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1)
        ->addAttributeToFilter('include_in_menu', 1);
```

unfortunately you cannot use

```
$categories = $categoty->getChildrenCategories();
$categories->addAttributeToFilter('include_in_menu', 1);
```

Like you should because on the first line the category collection is loaded and any oher filter does not affect it.

Comment: thanks a lot for reply,

\app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Layer\Filter/category.php

category.php file here = http://codepad.org/8MHoz2NJ

i think i can't simply replace the code in this file.

it's really going to be difficult for me to rewrite a method now....

from next time,  i will do it.

now can you please  rewrite method and  tell me which code i have to replace by which code....

Comment: [Here is an example on how you can rewrite a model](http://magedev.com/magento-overriding-model-block-or-helper/). And you only need to change the method `_getItemsData`. the code you need to replace is in the answer.

Comment: okay marius, i will try that and tell you later about result....